# Chart Js Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Using Chart js I am trying to pull data from Ajax call to supply to the Chart. 
I found a few other postings where people have suggested delaying the canvas load but nothing has seemed to work. Currently this is the what I have below and the error that I get is

[image]

```
$(function () {

GetChartData();

    function GetChartData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxURL,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (d) {
            //-------------
            //- BAR CHART -
            //-------------
            var barChartData = d;
            var barChartCanvas = $("#barChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
            var barChart = new Chart(barChartCanvas);
            // console.log(datajson);
            //barChartData.datasets[1].fillColor = "#00a65a";
            //barChartData.datasets[1].strokeColor = "#00a65a";
            //barChartData.datasets[1].pointColor = "#00a65a";
            var barChartOptions = {
                //Boolean - Whether the scale should start at zero, or an order of magnitude down from the lowest value
                //scaleBeginAtZero: true,
                //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
                scaleShowGridLines: true,
                //String - Colour of the grid lines
                scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
                //Number - Width of the grid lines
                scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
                //Boolean - Whether to show horizontal lines (except X axis)
                scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
                //Boolean - Whether to show vertical lines (except Y axis)
                scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
                //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar
                barShowStroke: true,
                //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke
                barStrokeWidth: 2,
                //Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
                barValueSpacing: 5,
                //Number - Spacing between data sets within X values
                barDatasetSpacing: 1,
                multiTooltipTemplate: "<%=datasetLabel%>: <%= value + ' %' %>",
                //String - A legend template
                legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>",
                //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: true
            };


            barChartOptions.datasetFill = false;
            barChart.Bar(barChartData, barChartOptions);


        }
    });
    }
});
```

**UPDATE HERE SHOWING HOW NON AJAX WORKS**

The below code is taking the results of the Ajax get request (which I got from dumping it to the console) and creating a "hard coded" version of the same thing. The only thing that should technically be different is one has the data loaded at time of the page and the second the data is loaded very briefly after.

```
 var chartData = {
    "labels": [
      "April"
    ],
    "datasets": [
      {
          "label": "Not Sure What to Put Here",
          "fillColor": "#662B60",
          "strokeColor": "#662B60",
          "pointColor": "#662B60",
          "pointStrokeColor": "#662B60",
          "pointHighlightFill": "#662B60",
          "pointHighlightStroke": "#662B60",
          "data": [
            1
          ]
      },
      {
          "label": "Not Sure What to Put Here",
          "fillColor": "#88B56E",
          "strokeColor": "#88B56E",
          "pointColor": "#88B56E",
          "pointStrokeColor": "#88B56E",
          "pointHighlightFill": "#88B56E",
          "pointHighlightStroke": "#88B56E",
          "data": [
            1
          ]
      },
      {
          "label": "Not Sure What to Put Here",
          "fillColor": "#48CA2B",
          "strokeColor": "#48CA2B",
          "pointColor": "#48CA2B",
          "pointStrokeColor": "#48CA2B",
          "pointHighlightFill": "#48CA2B",
          "pointHighlightStroke": "#48CA2B",
          "data": [
            0.83
          ]
      }
    ]
};


    //-------------
    //- BAR CHART -
    //-------------
var barChartData = chartData;
    var barChartCanvas = $("#barChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var barChart = new Chart(barChartCanvas);

    //barChartData.datasets[1].fillColor = "#00a65a";
    //barChartData.datasets[1].strokeColor = "#00a65a";
    //barChartData.datasets[1].pointColor = "#00a65a";
    var barChartOptions = {
        //Boolean - Whether the scale should start at zero, or an order of magnitude down from the lowest value
        //scaleBeginAtZero: true,
        //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
        scaleShowGridLines: true,
        //String - Colour of the grid lines
        scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
        //Number - Width of the grid lines
        scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
        //Boolean - Whether to show horizontal lines (except X axis)
        scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
        //Boolean - Whether to show vertical lines (except Y axis)
        scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
        //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar
        barShowStroke: true,
        //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke
        barStrokeWidth: 2,
        //Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
        barValueSpacing: 5,
        //Number - Spacing between data sets within X values
        barDatasetSpacing: 1,
        multiTooltipTemplate: "<%=datasetLabel%>: <%= value + ' %' %>",
        //String - A legend template
        legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>",
        //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true
    };


    barChartOptions.datasetFill = false;
    barChart.Bar(barChartData, barChartOptions);
```

**Update**
I changed from the min version of chart.js to the full version so I could see where exactly it was erroring out at.

Here is the image from chrome console 
[image]

Comment: You should validate you're getting the data in a format you expect from that AJAX call.  I'm going to assume after looking at the error, Chart.js isn't receiving any data somehow (or it's formatted incorrectly).

Comment: Shouldn't you replace `datasets` with `barChartData` ?

Comment: So I should have added that into the question. I dumped the data to the console so I could view it. I then copied that data and created a dummy var for it and assigned that var to the chart. So hard coded the data and it works so I can only assume it has something to do with the ajax call itself

Comment: christiondev. I could have just went with barChart.Bar(d, barChartOptions); but I was trying to keep as close to the example I was using as possible.

Comment: If anyone ends up coming here from Google, seeing the same error in a Google Chart visualisation, try changing the chart size. Really, I was getting this error because I had wrapped my chart in a Bootstrap class `card` and this was making the container too small. This actually caused this error in Google Charts w/ no error in the console in Chrome. Whef..

Comment: it is looking for `labels.length` and you have specified key as `label`.  so `labels` is effectively undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer,

The Ajax results has to be parsed first.

resulting fix

```
var barChartData = JSON.parse(d);
```

Answer (score 19):

The problem is that when your code executes, the canvas has not been created yet.
You should wrap your code inside a function and assign that function to window.onload event. You can see the sample code below.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "2015",
        data: [10, 8, 6, 5, 12, 8, 16, 17, 6, 7, 6, 10]
      }]
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Best answer dude

Answer (score 4):

For other users who have this problem, make sure your container canvas element exists, when called upon.

Answer (score 4):

running the following worked for me:

```
window.onload = function () {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try putting the Chart.JS script tag and other custom JS scripts just before the end of `**<**/body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an object that doesn't exist, well at least I cant see it, `datasets`.  I can only see `length` being called on this object, unless there's missing code?

I can see you assign `d` to `barChartData`

```
var barChartData = d;
```

So, you might want to replace the instances of `datasets` with `barChartData`.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but, I had this issue as well and in my case my data was length = 0. I solved this just adding a validation before calling the the graph:

```
if (barChartData.length > 0)
{
   objChart = Morris.Bar({....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error right after downloading & using a free bootstrap 5 admin template using the Chart JS package.

```
Chart.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
    at Object.acquireContext (Chart.min.js:7:76631)
    at ni.construct (Chart.min.js:7:92209)
    at new ni (Chart.min.js:7:91964)
    at chart-area-demo.js:7:19
```

In my console:

[image]

This is the initial code:

```
// Set new default font family and font color to mimic Bootstrap's default styling
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = '-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#292b2c';

// Area Chart Example
var ctx = document.getElementById("myAreaChart");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Mar 1", "Mar 2", "Mar 3", "Mar 4", "Mar 5", "Mar 6", "Mar 7", "Mar 8", "Mar 9", "Mar 10", "Mar 11", "Mar 12", "Mar 13"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Sessions",
            lineTension: 0.3,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)",
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
            pointHitRadius: 50,
            pointBorderWidth: 2,
            data: [10000, 30162, 26263, 18394, 18287, 28682, 31274, 33259, 25849, 24159, 32651, 31984, 38451],
        }],
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                time: {
                    unit: 'date'
                },
                gridLines: {
                    display: false
                },
                ticks: {
                    maxTicksLimit: 7
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 40000,
                    maxTicksLimit: 5
                },
                gridLines: {
                    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)",
                }
            }],
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    }
});
```

So what I did was to add a simple existence validation by using a conditional (IF). Like this:

```
// Set new default font family and font color to mimic Bootstrap's default styling
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = '-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#292b2c';

// Area Chart Example
var ctx = document.getElementById("myAreaChart");
if (ctx) {
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ["Mar 1", "Mar 2", "Mar 3", "Mar 4", "Mar 5", "Mar 6", "Mar 7", "Mar 8", "Mar 9", "Mar 10", "Mar 11", "Mar 12", "Mar 13"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Sessions",
                lineTension: 0.3,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,0.2)",
                borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
                pointRadius: 5,
                pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
                pointBorderColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)",
                pointHoverRadius: 5,
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
                pointHitRadius: 50,
                pointBorderWidth: 2,
                data: [10000, 30162, 26263, 18394, 18287, 28682, 31274, 33259, 25849, 24159, 32651, 31984, 38451],
            }],
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    time: {
                        unit: 'date'
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        maxTicksLimit: 7
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 40000,
                        maxTicksLimit: 5
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)",
                    }
                }],
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    });
}
```

No more errors after that.